# Comparing object string, stringify identity operator and string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, identity

I'm working on a reactjs component and my co-worker came across this issue with identity operators and JSON.stringify(). I am not sure why he was using a stringify in the code - but I was confused why these if/else blocks were not working.

Why do some of these comparison's not work, even though both have the same typeof?

So if the data was stored in local storage and they had to do a JSON.stringify - what is the next step to clear the data up to get a match?

https://jsfiddle.net/g8x761y2/6/

```
const objOne = {
  fruit: 'strawberry',
  nutrients: {
    minerals: {
      name: 'calcium'
    }
  }
};

const objTwo = {
  fruit: 'strawberry',
  nutrients: {
    minerals: {
      name: 'calcium'
    }
  }
};

const fruit = "strawberry"


console.log("obj fruit", objOne.fruit)
console.log("string fruite", fruit)

console.log("obj fruit type", typeof(objOne.fruit))
console.log("string fruit type", typeof(fruit))

console.log("obj fruit stringify type", typeof(JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit)))

console.log("isMatch with two stringify", JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === JSON.stringify(fruit))
console.log("isMatch with just one stringify", JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === fruit)


if (JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === "strawberry") {
  console.log("1")
}

if (objOne.fruit === "strawberry") {
  console.log("2")
}

if (JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === "strawberry" && JSON.stringify(fruit) === "strawberry") {
  console.log("3")
}

if (objOne.fruit === "strawberry" && fruit === "strawberry") {
  console.log("4")
}

if (JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === "strawberry" && fruit === "strawberry") {
  console.log("5")
}
```

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify()` to compare objects is quite risky. Even if two objects have the same property names and the same values, there's no guarantee that `JSON.stringify()` will output the property names in the same order.

Comment: That's what I came across - but why is this the case - why do these not work "even if two objects have the same property names and the same values"

Comment: Well, your last one (the `if` statement) is false - `JSON.stringify('strawberry') == "\"strawberry\""`.

Comment: Also - is there any reason to use JSON.stringify at this juncture - I think its only best to use it during use in localstorage -- getting and setting?

Comment: JavaScript property enumeration order is governed by rules that have to do with the lifecycle history of an object; there's no apparent consistency because the way an object gets to be the way it is can vary. That's just the way the language is defined.

Comment: @Pointy He's not comparing objects here through, right? He's only watching the behavior of `JSON.stringify` when it's called on a *string*

Comment: @CertainPerformance yea re-reading it I think you're right; I get really nervous about people doing such object comparisons so I tend to panic easily. However it also makes me even more confused about what's going on here.

Comment: So if the data was stored in local storage and they had to do a JSON.stringify - what is the next step to clear the data up to get a match?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wq2135dL/

Answer (score 2):

When using `JSON.stringify` on *primitives*, the stringification process must be able to reflect the *type* of primitive it was originally, so that deserialization using `JSON.parse` results in an identical copy. So, when `JSON.stringify`ing a string, double quotes are put around the string:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify('foo'));
```

This is to distingish, for example, a stringified string of `false`, from a stringified *boolean* of `false` (or a stringified string of `'23'` from a stringified *number* of `23`).

Thus, your tests of

```
JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) === "strawberry"
```

do not evaluate to `true`, because it's testing whether

```
'"strawberry"' === "strawberry"
```

Strings, when stringified, contain delimiters at their first and last indicies, whereas the original strings do not have those delimiters.

Comment: ok - so why does JSON.stringify(objOne.fruit) - get wrapped in single quotes - and what is the step to resolve this? do a .replace?

Comment: Just use `objOne.fruit` in the comparison.

Comment: The outer delimiters (whether `'` or `"`) are the string delimiters (required for Javascript syntax to indicate that something is a string).

Comment: @TheOldCounty Unless you *need* to serialize or deserialize, there's no sense in invoking `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`. Here, best to just reference the plain value, eg `objOne.fruit`

Comment: I am trying to reverse what I was looking at earlier today. I think maybe JSON.stringify was used because the object was stored in localstorage

Comment: So if the data was stored in local storage and they had to do a JSON.stringify - what is the next step to clear the data up to get a match?

Comment: @TheOldCounty Use `JSON.parse`, *once*, on the serialized data

Comment: Ah - so he may need JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify  --- hard to pair program when you come across something like this

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: so he may need JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify?

Comment: @TheOldCounty The input objects in the fiddles / the question are already usable as objects, so trying to manipulate them after stringifying them doesn't make much sense - given the current situation, it looks like you can avoid the `JSON` methods entirely, and instead just compare the plain object values.

Comment: yes - but the co-worker must have used them for a reason - I guess it came out of a localstorage

Comment: @TheOldCounty Can you give a specific example of the input and the expected output (perhaps from certain comparisons)? It's impossible to say what the issue might be without a [MCVE] of what you have and what you're hoping to get as a result - if you're actually using inputs from localStorage, show your inputs as localStorage items (which are always strings)

Comment: I can't remember etc.. don't have the full code - I only took a glance at this for a few minutes - but it got me wondering and creating the test code